# Using GNU Parallel to scp huge file splitting it by chunk per host

Tags: linux, ssh, scp, ansible, gnu-parallel

I'm using Ansible to set up some configuration on several nodes, and as part of this setup I need to split one big file by *n* lines and copy each part to a remote file without creating local copy of each chunk (like bash *split* command does). Ansible can't do this by default (or I just didn't find out how to do it yet), so I decided to use GNU Parallel. I found out [here](https://superuser.com/questions/291829/how-do-i-scp-the-huge-output-of-a-command-directly-to-a-remote-machine) that copying from stdin may be easily done like this:

```
~$ echo "Lots of data" | ssh user@example.com 'cat > big.txt'
```

But I want to do this simultaneously to several hosts! So, here is an example input:

```
~$ cat hosts.txt
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
3.3.3.3

~$ cat data.txt
lots
of
...
lines
```

I calculate number of lines per node by doing "wc -l" and dividing second number by first. So, basically, next step would be something like this:

```
~$ cat data.txt | parallel -S `cat hosts.txt | tr "\n" ","` -N $LINES_PER_HOST --pipe "ssh $HOST 'cat > /data/piece.txt'"
```

but how can I launch one command for each host, what should I replace $HOST with? I thought about combining two inputs (one being hosts), but still no idea how to do it.

Would really appreciate any thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works from version 20150922:

```
parallel-20150922 -a bigfile --roundrobin  --pipepart --slf hosts.txt -j1 'cat > giraf'
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I only see one limitation - I can only split file by blocks, not by lines. Will it always process line endings correctly in this case? I don't really care if one node gets a little more lines than the other, but I need lines to be complete and readable.

Comment: It splits on \n, so you should be safe.

Comment: I launched it on file with 10000 lines and 2 nodes, using block size a little larger that 'du -b' output divided by two. One node got ~4850 lines, the other one ~4900, the rest is lost. Is there any way to ensure all lines are copied? Or I should calculate block size in some other way?

Comment: You should never lose lines. Can you post the exact command you wrote? If you run the command I give, --block is not needed.